# Diferentes formas de criar um iterator para valores

Tags: javascript, array, característica-linguagem, iterator

Existe alguma diferença entre criar um *iterator* para os valores de um array usando essas duas formas?

```
let myIterator = arr[Symbol.iterator]()
let myIterator2 = arr.values()
```

Fiz alguns testes e pelo menos o resultado aparenta ser o mesmo. Gostaria de saber se "nas entranhas" há alguma diferença como performance ou outras características relevantes.

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com a especificação de [`Array.prototype[@@iterator]`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-array.prototype-@@iterator):

> O valor inicial da propriedade `@@iterator` é o mesmo função-objeto que o valor inicial da propriedade `Array.prototype.values`.

<sup>Se você achou o termo "função-objeto" estranho, não deixe de consultar esta [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/480170/69296).</sup>

Desse modo, não há nenhuma diferença entre os dois jeitos de se executar esse método. É a exata mesma função, que é compartilhada entre essas propriedades. Não há, também, diferença de performance.

No entanto, creio que usar o método `values` seja mais preferido nesse caso, já que é um método criado para ser usado diretamente pelo desenvolvedor. O `@@iterator`, no entanto, além de ser menos claro, foi implementado para ser usado pela própria linguagem, como parte do [protocolo de iteração](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) da linguagem.