# Por que Arrays e Funções são Objetos?

Tags: javascript, array, funções, terminologia, objetos

Eu aprendi que objetos armazenam propriedades e métodos:

```
let objeto = {
  propriedade: "valor da propriedade",
  metodo: function() {
    return "retorno"
  }
}
```

Mas vejo sites chamando funções e arrays de "objetos" e gostaria de saber o porquê.

Comment: Função sendo chamado de objeto em qual contexto? Se você der `typeof objeto.metodo` o retorno será `function`.

Comment: tem uma resposta no site mas, não encontro

Comment: No site da mozzila:https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#:~:text=Em%20JavaScript%2C%20fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20s%C3%A3o%20objetos,Guia%20de%20JavaScript%20sobre%20fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es.

diz o seguinte: "Em JavaScript, funções são objetos de primeira classe, pois elas podem ter propriedades e métodos como qualquer outro objeto. O que as difere de outros objetos é que as funções podem ser chamados. Em resumo, elas são objetos Function."
É nisso que eu fico confuso, como você mesmo disse o typeof mostra "function" e não "object"

Comment: Se você for subindo na cadeia de protótipos, sempre vai chegar a um objeto. `typeof Function.prototype.__proto__ === "object"`. Isso é uma decisão de projeto da linguagem. Com exceção dos tipos primitivos, os demais derivam de Object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acordo com a [especificação da linguagem](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-object-type):

> An Object is logically a collection of properties.

Que, em tradução livre, significa que um objeto é, do ponto de vista lógico, uma coleção de propriedades.

Assim, pode-se dizer que, em JavaScript, qualquer valor capaz de possuir propriedades é um objeto. Esse não é o caso dos primitivos (`undefined`, `null`, `boolean`, `number`, `bigint`, `string` e `symbol`).

Esta [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/474567/69296) explica porque você ainda consegue acessar propriedades em valores primitivos. Em resumo, deve-se ao conceito de [*primitive wrapping*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/Primitivo#Wrappers_em_JavaScript).

---

Logo, uma função é um objeto porque ela é uma estrutura capaz de conter propriedades (ao contrário dos primitivos, que precisam do *primitive wrapping* para tal). Ademais, a [documentação de funções](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) também deixa claro que uma função é um objeto:

> Toda função em JavaScript é, na verdade, um objeto `Function`.

Já um *array* nada mais é que um objeto cujas propriedades [enumeráveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/478411/69296) são numéricas. Possui também uma propriedade não enumerável `length` — que determina seu comprimento —, além de "herdar" as propriedades de [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype). Formalmente, o *array* é descrito pela especificação como um [*exotic object*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-array-exotic-objects).

---

Em relação ao operador `typeof`, um *array* sempre será visto como `"object"`. No entanto, uma função, embora também seja um objeto, será considerada `"function"`. Esse comportamento [é esperado](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#table-35), já que `"function"` é retornado por esse operador para objetos que possuem a propriedade interna `[[Call]]` definida (o que é o caso das funções).

```js
// Primitivos
console.log(typeof undefined); // undefined
console.log(typeof null); // object
console.log(typeof true); // boolean
console.log(typeof 123); // number
console.log(typeof 123n); // bigint
console.log(typeof 'str'); // string
console.log(typeof Symbol('foo')); // symbol

console.log('---');

// Objetos
console.log(typeof {}); // object
console.log(typeof []); // object
console.log(typeof alert); // function
```

Você pode ter notado que `typeof null` é `"object"`. Embora `null` seja um primitivo, a descrição de `null` para ECMAScript é "a ausência interna de qualquer valor objeto". Há quem diga que isso é um *bug* (na primeira versão da linguagem). Outros dizem que foi uma escolha pelo criador da linguagem, Brendan Eich. De qualquer jeito, para manter a compatibilidade entre navegadores, o comportamento teve que ser mantido. <sub>[[Referência.]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18808300/7445826)</sub>

Comment: Na verdade a justificativa para `typeof null` ser `object` é a [compatibilidade com códigos legados](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null). Isso é de fato considerado um bug da linguagem, que provavelmente não será corrigido porque muitos códigos fazem uso desse bug, e mudar seu comportamento iria quebra-los.

Comment: @user140828, na verdade, essa justificativa entra num certo debate. [Esta resposta no StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18808300/7445826) comenta sobre isso um pouco mais detalhadamente. De qualquer jeito, editei essa parte na resposta, obrigado pela observação. :-)

Comment: *"para manter a compatibilidade entre navegadores"*, está aí a justificativa de muita coisa "estranha" no JavaScript