# Por que Math é do tipo object em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, objetos

Na literatura `Math` é do tipo `"object"`, contudo, o conceito de `object` em sua estrutura é do tipo chave/valor. E não vejo a estrutra de objeto em `Math`, preciso entender melhor.

Comment: E por que `Math` não seria chave-valor? `Math.floor`, por exemplo, evidência que `Math` é, de fato, um objeto, sendo, nesse caso, `Math` o objeto e `floor` uma propriedade (que, como é uma função, pode ser também ser chamado de método — nesse caso “estático” também).

Comment: Certo felipe, entao pelo que entendi como o conceito de object é chave e valor (math = chave/floor = valor), seria isso seu raciocínio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com a [especificação](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-object), um valor do tipo `"object"` é (em tradução livre):

> Um objeto é uma coleção de propriedades. [...]

Portanto, `Math` é um objeto já que é, de fato, uma coleção de propriedades. Quando você acessa, por exemplo, `Math.floor` ou `Math.PI`, evidentemente se trata de um objeto (o operador `.` denota acesso de propriedade em um objeto).

Uma outra forma de depreender que `Math` é objeto é constatar que ele não é nenhum dos primitivos da linguagem. Portanto, como `Math` não corresponde a nenhum outro tipo primitivo (`undefined`, `null`, `boolean`, `number`, `bigint`, `string` e `symbol`), ele só pode ser um objeto.

Vale ressaltar que todas as [funções são objetos em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/480170/69296). No entanto, a recíproca não é verdadeira, isto é, nem todo objeto é uma função, como é o caso do próprio `Math`, que é "apenas" um objeto.

Para mais detalhes técnicos, consulte a especificação de [`Math`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-math-object). E a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math).

---

Esse tipo de objeto (como [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math), [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)) foram criados para servir de "namespace". Em versões anteriores ao ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), o JavaScript não possuía um padrão de módulos nativamente. Desse modo, para não fazer "feio" e deixar funções como matemáticas como `abs`, `floor`, `ceil`, `sin` etc no escopo global, criou-se esse tipo de "objeto namespace", isto é, com o objetivo de agrupar funções "de um mesmo domínio" em um mesmo objeto.

Se módulos estivessem disponíveis desde o começo, você provavelmente faria:

```js
import { floor } from 'std:math'; // NÃO EXISTE. Apenas demonstrando uma possibilidade.

floor(4.34); // 4
```

Ao invés de:

```
js
Math.floor(4.34); //4
```

Existe [uma proposta](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-built-in-modules) (atualmente no estágio 1) para padronizar uma "biblioteca padrão" em formato de módulos para JavaScript. Contudo, ainda parece estar bem prematura e provavelmente vai demorar para avançar.

---

Cabe frisar também que o `Math` não é um objeto função. Isso porque ele não implementa a propriedade interna `[[Call]]`. Portanto, `Math` não pode ser invocado (<s>`Math()`</s> está errado — e não faz nenhum sentido). Também não pode ser utilizado para construir objetos com `new` já que não implementa o método interno `[[Construct]]`.

Comment: Muito Obrigado.