# Como manter uma cópia original ao utilizar o sort em arrays do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, objetos, classificação

Preciso ordenar um array, mas não posso perder a sequencia original.

Para isso, criei uma nova variável e atribui o valor a ela, fazendo uma cópia da original. Entretanto, ao utilizar o método `sort`, percebi que ele modifica as duas variáveis. Segue o trecho do código:

```
var rank = [292, 130, 55, 232, 213, 62, 152], rankOdered = [];
rankOrdered = rank;

console.log("rankOdered: " + rankOrdered)
console.log("rank: " + rank)
console.log("")

rankOrdered.sort(function (a, b) { return b - a });

console.log("rankOdered: " + rankOrdered)
console.log("rank: " + rank)
```

Na tela do console:

```
rankOdered: 292,130,55,232,213,62,152
rank: 292,130,55,232,213,62,152
<empty string>
rankOdered: 292,232,213,152,130,62,55
rank: 292,232,213,152,130,62,55
```

Comment: Eu costumo chamar a função `.splice()` antes de `.sort()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você não está fazendo, de fato, uma cópia do array. Repare aqui:

```
var rank = [292, 130, 55, 232, 213, 62, 152];
var rankOrdered = rank;
```

Quando você faz `var rankOrdered = rank`, você está atribuindo, à `rankOrdered`, a referência do array original, que no caso é `rank`.

Portanto, qualquer modificação feita no array `rankOrdered` também irá se refletir no array `rank` (e vice-versa), já que as duas variáveis apontam para o mesmo objeto ([sim, arrays são objetos em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/480170/69296)).

E o que ocorre é que o método `Array.prototype.sort` não realiza as modificações em um novo array. O `sort` faz as modificações *in-place*. Desse modo, o `sort` modificará o array que a ele for aplicado.

Então, o que você precisa fazer é uma cópia de fato. Existem [várias formas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085/7445826) de se fazer isso. Por exemplo, utilizando o *spread operator*:

```js
var rank = [292, 130, 55, 232, 213, 62, 152];
var rankOrdered = [...rank]; // Agora sim, cria-se um novo array.

rankOrdered.sort((a, b) => b - a);

console.log(rank);
console.log(rankOrdered);
```